# Unable to make new project in drools workbench

Tags: wildfly, drools, kie-workbench

While trying to create new project from drools, I am getting error -

> Non-readable POM : input contained no data

I am not able to debug the reason for this, as I am using the default war for drools workbench, downloaded from [link](https://www.drools.org/download/download.html), and my wildfly version(application server) is **14.0.1**

Logs for same are -

```
15:16:43,465 INFO  [org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.repositories.FileSystemArtifactRepository] (default task-7) Maven Repository root set to: repositories/kie/global/
15:16:43,465 INFO  [org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.repositories.FileSystemArtifactRepository] (default task-7) Creating Maven Repository root: repositories/kie/global/
15:17:10,406 INFO  [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (default task-7) Erasing directory from local maven repository /Users/b0206714/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-internal/7.18.0.Final
15:17:10,411 ERROR [org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader] (default task-7) Unable to create MavenProject from InputStream: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[FATAL] **Non-readable POM : input contained no data @ 
 for project** 
       at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:168)
       at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:126)
       at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.readProject(MavenEmbedder.java:308)
       at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:91)
       at org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:84)
       at org.guvnor.common.services.project.backend.server.ModuleRepositoryResolverImpl.getRemoteRepositoriesMetaData(ModuleRepositoryResolverImpl.java:143)
       at org.guvnor.common.services.project.backend.server.ModuleRepositoryResolverImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getRemoteRepositoriesMetaData(Unknown Source)
       at org.guvnor.common.services.project.backend.server.AbstractModuleRepositoriesServiceImpl.create(AbstractModuleRepositoriesServiceImpl.java:72)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieModuleRepositoriesServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.create(Unknown Source)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.ModuleSaver$NewModuleCreator.createModule(ModuleSaver.java:156)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.ModuleSaver$NewModuleCreator.create(ModuleSaver.java:123)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.ModuleSaver.save(ModuleSaver.java:94)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieModuleServiceImpl.newModule(KieModuleServiceImpl.java:106)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieModuleServiceImpl.newModule(KieModuleServiceImpl.java:47)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieModuleServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.newModule(Unknown Source)
       at org.guvnor.common.services.project.backend.server.WorkspaceProjectServiceImpl.newProject(WorkspaceProjectServiceImpl.java:168)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.screens.impl.LibraryServiceImpl.createProject(LibraryServiceImpl.java:228)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.screens.impl.LibraryServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.createProject(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.jboss.errai.bus.server.io.AbstractRPCMethodCallback.invokeMethodFromMessage(AbstractRPCMethodCallback.java:65)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

```
15:17:10,545 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (Thread-164) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component IOWatchServiceExecutorImpl for method public abstract void org.uberfire.backend.server.io.watch.IOWatchServiceExecutor.execute(org.uberfire.java.nio.file.WatchKey,org.uberfire.backend.server.util.Filter): javax.ejb.EJBException: **org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: No filesystem for uri (default://master@MySpace/abc/src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml) found.**
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInNoTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:223)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.notSupported(CMTTxInterceptor.java:345)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:142)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
       at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:106)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
       at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)
       at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
       at org.uberfire.backend.server.io.watch.IOWatchServiceExecutor$$$view1.execute(Unknown Source)
       at org.uberfire.backend.server.io.watch.AbstractIOWatchService$2.execute(AbstractIOWatchService.java:179)
       at org.uberfire.backend.server.io.watch.AbstractIOWatchService$3.run(AbstractIOWatchService.java:212)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: No filesystem for uri (default://master@MySpace/abc/src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml) found.
       at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.deepLookupFSFrom(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:819)
       at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.getPath(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:742)
       at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:81)
       at org.uberfire.backend.server.util.Paths.convert(Paths.java:63)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieResourceResolver.resolveModule(KieResourceResolver.java:74)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieResourceResolver.resolveModule(KieResourceResolver.java:43)
       at org.guvnor.common.services.project.backend.server.ResourceResolver.resolveModule(ResourceResolver.java:167)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieModuleServiceImpl.resolveModule(KieModuleServiceImpl.java:127)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieModuleServiceImpl.resolveModule(KieModuleServiceImpl.java:47)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieModuleServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.resolveModule(Unknown Source)
       at org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeObserver.processBatchResourceChanges(ResourceChangeObserver.java:149)
       at org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeObserver.processBatchChanges(ResourceChangeObserver.java:112)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
       at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
       at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
       at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:124)
       at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:96)
       at org.uberfire.backend.server.io.watch.IOWatchServiceExecutorImpl.execute(IOWatchServiceExecutorImpl.java:132)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
       at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)
       at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:53)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInNoTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:216)
       ... 40 more
```

```
15:17:10,549 ERROR [org.uberfire.backend.server.io.watch.AbstractIOWatchService] (Thread-164) Unexpected error during WatchService execution: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: No filesystem for uri (default://master@MySpace/abc/src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml) found.
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInNoTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:223)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.notSupported(CMTTxInterceptor.java:345)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:142)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
       at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:106)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
       at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)
       at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
       at org.uberfire.backend.server.io.watch.IOWatchServiceExecutor$$$view1.execute(Unknown Source)
       at org.uberfire.backend.server.io.watch.AbstractIOWatchService$2.execute(AbstractIOWatchService.java:179)
       at org.uberfire.backend.server.io.watch.AbstractIOWatchService$3.run(AbstractIOWatchService.java:212)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.uberfire.java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: No filesystem for uri (default://master@MySpace/abc/src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml) found.
       at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.deepLookupFSFrom(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:819)
       at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.getPath(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:742)
       at org.uberfire.java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:81)
       at org.uberfire.backend.server.util.Paths.convert(Paths.java:63)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieResourceResolver.resolveModule(KieResourceResolver.java:74)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieResourceResolver.resolveModule(KieResourceResolver.java:43)
       at org.guvnor.common.services.project.backend.server.ResourceResolver.resolveModule(ResourceResolver.java:167)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieModuleServiceImpl.resolveModule(KieModuleServiceImpl.java:127)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieModuleServiceImpl.resolveModule(KieModuleServiceImpl.java:47)
       at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.KieModuleServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.resolveModule(Unknown Source)
       at org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeObserver.processBatchResourceChanges(ResourceChangeObserver.java:149)
       at org.guvnor.common.services.builder.ResourceChangeObserver.processBatchChanges(ResourceChangeObserver.java:112)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
       at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
       at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
       at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.ObserverMethod.notify(ObserverMethod.java:124)
       at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:166)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
       at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:96)
       at org.uberfire.backend.server.io.watch.IOWatchServiceExecutorImpl.execute(IOWatchServiceExecutorImpl.java:132)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at
```

Comment: Are you able to load one of the sample projects? How are you creating your project, clicking new project in the default space? Can you create a new space?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using proxy/corporate proxy to go through internet?
if yes, you can try by adding maven settings.xml in the .m2 folder with proxy configuration.

```xml
<settings>
<proxies>
<proxy>
<id>example-proxy</id>
<active>true</active>
<protocol>http</protocol>
<host>proxyHost</host>
<port>3128</port>
<!-<username>username</username>->
<!-- <password>password</password> -->
</proxy>
</settings>
```

thanks to this

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-8027?focusedCommentId=13730738&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel